# How to calculate returns using time series data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, time-series, percentage

I have time series data in below format

```
{
    "_id" : "adfsdgsd",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.0
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.279
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.208
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.243
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.313
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.353
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-23T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.376
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.4
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.406
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-28T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.366
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.43
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.462
        }, 
        {
            "d" : ISODate("2006-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "v" : 10.498
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to calculate last 1 week returns in mongo

Comment: So what will be the expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way you have stored your data any query will return that whole object. Now you just need to query that object locally using your chosen programming language.

To get MongoDB to do the work you would be better storing the date and value objects as top-level documents e.g.

```
{
   "d" : ISODate("2006-11-14T00:00:00.000Z"),
   "v" : 10.0
}
```

If you need other identifying info it could be embedded in that doc. Now to find any range of values you can do,

```
db.col.find( { "d" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2006-11-29T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lte" :  ISODate("2006-12-01T00:00:00.000Z")}})
```

then you could total the `v` values in code. Alternatively you could use the aggregation framework.

```
> match
{
    "$match" : {
        "d" : {
            "$gte" : ISODate("2006-11-29T00:00:00Z"),
            "$lte" : ISODate("2006-12-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }
}
> db.col.aggregate( [match, {"$group" : { "_id" : "range_sum", "total" : {"$sum": "$v"}}}])
{ "_id" : "range_sum", "total" : 31.39 }
>
```

See [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) documentation for details.

I do recommend adding an [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) on the `d` field to make querying efficient.